# Create a plot between X & Y with background tile shading based on Z

Tags: ggplot2

Hi I have a data which has three columns

1. Date
2. Close (numeric)
3. State (1,2,3 integer values)

I want to plot a Close vs Date chart with shaded areas of different colour based on the states.

#### Code

```
Price<-data.frame(y,NTRI$NTRI.Close[15:nrow(NTRI),],HMMpost[,1])
colnames(Price) <- c( "Date","Close", "State")
xstart<- as.Date(Price$Date[[1]])
xend<- as.Date(Price$Date[[nrow(Price)]])
rects<- data.frame(xstart= xstart, xend= xend, col= letters[1:3])

ggplot() + 
    geom_line(data = Price, aes(x = Date, y = Close)) + 
    geom_rect(data = rects, 
              aes(xmin = xstart, xmax = xend, 
                  ymin = 0, ymax = +Inf, fill = col), 
              alpha = 0.5)
```

#### Data

```
structure(list(Close = c(22.89, 23.51, 23.45, 24.72, 26.76, 27.74, 28.62, 26.9, 30.58, 28.79, 27.25, 27.44, 23.79, 24.26, 23.33, 25.26, 24.89, 23.11, 23.89), Date = structure(c(13901, 13902, 13903, 13906, 13907, 13908, 13909, 13910, 13913, 13914, 13915, 13916, 13917, 13920, 13921, 13922, 13923, 13924, 13928), class = "Date"), State = c(3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -19L))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ggplot(data = Price, aes(x = Date, y = Close)) +
    geom_rect(aes(ymin = 0, ymax = Inf,
                  xmin = Date, xmax = lead(Date), 
                  fill = as.factor(State)), alpha =0.5) + 
    geom_line() +
    geom_point()
```

[image: 1]